# PHP script for front-end management of MySql tables

Tags: mysql, database, frontend

I'm looking for a PHP script that will allow me to easily manage 'MySql' tables. By managing I mean not their creation but the possibility of adding new records, modifying and deleting them.
It must be possible to specify for each user which tables he will have access to and with which modalities (insertion only, modification only, etc.).
For each user I will also have to specify whether he will be able to see all or some of the columns in the table and with which permissions.
Also I'll need to know who did what, a sort of global change LOG.

My idea was to have a back-end in which I specified the users and how to access the various tables/columns and a front-end for the users.
In the front-end users will be able to add/modify/delete records and data they are allowed and the ability to filter and/or sort the various records.

I know I could use some PHP frameworks or rely on CMS but I have to write a lot of code by hand and it seems hardly credible that such a product is not already available.

Does anyone know if there is something like this?

I had tried starting with PHP frameworks but implementing everything from scratch stopped me.
I expect there is already something available.

Thanks.
Davide.

Comment: Have you tried phpmyadmin? If so, what do you need that it can't do?

Comment: @SimonGoater, thanks for the suggestion. I use phpmyadmin many times but it's not good for my purpose because it doesn't give me the possibility to lock the properties for columns (for some users, some columns I would like to have only readable, others editable, others completely invisible). Apart from the fact that many table field names are difficult and I can't rename them as they are already used directly by some web pages.
Furthermore, having my database hosted at a web provider, I don't have the possibility to activate the log that records all the changes made by the various users.

Comment: Today I'm doing internet searches with the terms "php code generator" or more specifically "php generator users fields web application" even though I still haven't found what I need.
I also searched for "crud php generator" but I get results of use items at a lower programming level.

Comment: It isn't normal practice to have users editing tables. You are introducing all sorts of security issues. I suggest you do it the normal way and develop an application that provides an interface between the users and the database. Then you can can customise your application as you like. Your requirements sound pretty specific. I'm not optimistic you'll find something that does just what you want.

Comment: I think I have found various products that suit my purpose.
They are something like "PHP Generator for MySQL" or "PHP code
generator", etc. I have some commercial product names but I think I can't put them here.

Comment: I can understand that it is usually not normal for users to have access to tables in a database.
In our case, however, we have tables used by various internet pages used in turn by our customers.
The purpose of allowing some employees partial access to these tables allows us to manage independently to change the contents of these pages. Naturally my need is to allow access with various roles to the various employees (who can only consult them, who can only modify and who can also insert new records). Of course, all with log of all changes made.

Thank you.